# How to solve error generate python3 code in ANTLR 4.4 ?

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I am using ANTLR 4.4 with Python3 as target language. You can see in this page: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/releases that ANTLR 4.4 suppors Python3 but when I want to create a Python lexer & parser with this command: -Dlanguage=Python3 MyGrammar.g4 , I got this error:

```
 ANTLR cannot generate python3 code as of version 4.4
```

I don't know it is because of my grammar and I have to modify it to resolve this error or waht?(BTW I got no error in ANTLRWorks 2.1)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you use the bild tool as recommended? When working in Antlrworks2 the generated code that is used e.g. for the test rig is always in Java.

Comment: I used ANTLRWorks2 just for writing my grammar not generating lexer & Parser. I got them directly from antlr4.

Comment: ok. As I said: Antlrworks produces no error as it's not using Python. Maybe you can post your complete command that creates the parser/lexer along with the complete error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is removed by change the definition of CLASSPATH.
First I specified it permanently:
    Using System Properties dialog > Environment variables > Create or append to CLASSPATH variable

then I changed it to temporary as follows:
    SET CLASSPATH=.;C:\Javalib\antlr-4.4-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%
and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned here https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Python+Target :

- antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 MyGrammar.g4 
  or
- antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 MyGrammar.g4

Answer (score 0):

### It might just be a typo (I ran into the same problem and I solved it by using capital P in Python):

```bash
$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=python3 grammar.g4 
error(31):  ANTLR cannot generate python3 code as of version 4.11.1
```

### Solution

```
$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 grammar.g4
```

Comment: Note, I do have a different version than in question, but the error was the same as mine.